# Mouse click listener on the shape doesn't work in actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript, click, mouse

Could you help me please with this issue:
I have created shapes and have putted Mouse click listener on them with the same listener function, but the function doesn't get called.

```
   shape:Shape = new Shape
   shape.graphics.beginFill(color); 
   shape.graphics.drawRoundRect(rx, ry, cWidth, cHeigth, ellipseHeight, ellipseHeight);
   shape.graphics.endFill();
   shape.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onMouseClick);
   areaSprite.addChild(shape);


   private function onMouseClick(ev:MouseEvent):void {
      // some code
      ..........
   }
```

What I'm doing wrong here ?  could you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Shape objects are non interactive, so they do not fire mouse events, etc.

Instead of using Shape, use another object that inherits from an InteractiveObject.
Sprite may be a good option.

But, if I am doing something with the graphics object, I always declare my object as MovieClip.

```
shape:Sprite = new Sprite();
```

or

```
shape:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
```

Look at the inherited events for Shape here;
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Shape.html

... and compare to the inherited events for Sprite here;
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html